# I am not able to render static images while packaging node-express app using pkg

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, packaging

While trying to render an image from the public folder in my express app it is not rendering it.Can anyone help me how to configure the path so that I am able to render the images or css files in the public folder
while creating a executable file using pkg.
Attaching the code

```
app.use(express.static(Path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
console.log(Path.join(__dirname, 'public/images'));
res.render(Path.join(__dirname, 'views/' + 'testing'), {
    variable: Path.join(__dirname, 'public/images/' + 'category.png')
});
});
app.listen(3003, function() {
console.log('listening port 3003');
});
```

[image: Image from google console]

[image]

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg#detecting-assets-in-source-code

Answer (score 1):

Try to move a level up to the `../public` directory in your file path if the express code is at the root level of a directory that is at the same level as the `public` directory. The path depends on where you are using `app.use(express.static(publicDirectoryPath))`

```
    const publicDirectoryPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public'); 

    app.use(express.static(publicDirectoryPath));
```